# bootstrap toggle collapse pancake button that doesnt cover page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I got the toggle-collapse pancake button to work for small screens, but when the menu expands, it covers part of the screen. How can I get the menu to expand w.o covering the screen? I tried lowering the body, but that doesnt work well.

```
<!doctyp html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">        
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            body { padding-top:50px; }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container">

                        <!-- The button that shows when the width is too short -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">                            
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>

                            <a class="navbar-brand" ><span class="subhead"></span>Project 1</a>
                        </div>                   
                            <!-- The navigation menu. It collapses when the width is too short -->
                            <div id="collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li><a href="#browse">browse</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#why">why</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>                                    
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

        </header>


        <section>
            <h3>Project 1 incomplete</h3>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </section>

    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have not mentioned that you required fixed top behavior, So without this behavior it works.

If you want fixed top behavior then it needs to be managed by JavaScript.

Please check below code snippet and post your comment if it is helpful to you:

```css
  body { padding-top:0px; }
```

```html
<!doctyp html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">        
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container">

                        <!-- The button that shows when the width is too short -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">                            
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>

                            <a class="navbar-brand" ><span class="subhead"></span>Project 1</a>
                        </div>                   
                            <!-- The navigation menu. It collapses when the width is too short -->
                            <div id="collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li><a href="#browse">browse</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#why">why</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>                                    
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

        </header>


        <section>
            <h3>Project 1 incomplete</h3>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </section>

    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the navigation must be fixed atop. Your tip did give me some new ideas too. I think javascript is the way.